# String Cocatenation In java

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I have a string where i am trying to concatenate string with " but when i am concatenating string with " it is not happening in java.I mean to say that concatenating " is not happening with String..Here is my current String formate which i need to change..

```
"userdata":{'totalcdrcost':'302.92'}
```

whereas my need is to show it like ..

```
"userdata":{"totalcdrcost":"302.92"}
```

I tried to concatenate **"** in the String but i am not able to concatenate **"** in the String due to which i am not able to complete the task.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your issue might be that you're writing a literal `"` inside a string literal without escaping it as `\"`. Or not, as you did not provide any code.

Comment: @Darkhogg yes sir i am trying to write a literal " inside a string literal whcih is not hapening ..Please tell me how to do it with escape..

Comment: use \" and you are done

Comment: What @HussainAkhtarWahid said. "\"userdata\"" + ":{\"totalcdrcost\":" + "\"+ totalcdrcost +\"}"

Comment: @Nyx : sry for incomplete ans man , and thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use String.concat() with escape character. Like mentioned in all the comments above !!!

```
String str="Sample";
str=str.concat("\"");
System.out.println(str); // Sample"
```